# Declare variable without type

Tags: ios, swift

I need to declare a variable as follows:

```
var cell

if cond {
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCell1
}
else {
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCell2
}
```

The problem here is that I get the error `Type annotation missing in pattern`.

Of what type should I declare my variable or is there a workaround this issue?

Comment: You probably want to give it the type of a common ancestor of both classes. I guess that would be `UITableViewCell`. Or if you have common extra properties, some custom common superclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `CustomCell1` and `CustomCell2` inherit from `UICollectionViewCell` you can do the following:

```
var x: UICollectionViewCell?

if cond {
    x = CustomCell1()
}
else {
    x = CustomCell2()
}
```

Then when you want to use it as a specific type of cell you use this:

```
if let cell1 = x as? CustomCell1 {
    //Use cell1 here
}

if let cell2 = x as? CustomCell2 {
    //Use cell2 here
}
```

Comment: I have replaced `UITableViewCell` with `UICollectionViewCell`. This should work now

Comment: No problem, if this has answered your question please mark it as so :) Glad i could help

Comment: That's because your not using `if let cell1 = x as? CustomCell1` etc, you are trying to access the properties without casting it first.